# C++ exception: std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, memory-management

For simplicity, please consider this class with 3 attributes.

```
class Human
{
   public:
     int id;
     int age;
     std::string name;
};

int main()
{
Human *h = new Human[120000]; <-- breaking
    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is
 Unhandled exception at at 0x76ACC52F in Human.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x000D0EA8.

The machine where this program is running has 32 GB RAM and 1 TB Harddrive with paging on. The Human class has about 350 attributes. I checked and found that each Human object takes about 29000 bytes. So total it should be allocating 29000 X 120000 = 3.48 GB

I am assuming this is a memory problem where the program doesn't have enough memory to complete the new operation. By why. 32 GB isnt a small memory. There isn't any other program running other than Visual Studio running this C++ program.

Please let me know your thoughts in this matter and a probable resolution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130287/discussion-on-question-by-blue-piranha-c-exception-stdbad-alloc).

Answer (score 0):

So as shown in the comments compiling in 64 bit solves the problem but you should probably use a linked list instead of an array because it doesn't require a contiguous block of memory.

Comment: probably terrible performance-side to do that... splitting the array into some chunks would probably be much more efficient. accessing a random element in a linked list is O(n).

Comment: ... or dynamically allocating `Human`s which would probably save some space in that contiguous block.